# How to remove newline Line Feed based on a condition in Unix

Tags: linux, unix

I have a input file input.txt which has few lines ending with `\` now I want to remove the Line Feeds from the lines having `\` as the end character using shell script.

input.txt  ==>

```
This is Datafile
Which contains Raw Data \
Make Sure \
To Clean this file \
Thanks in advance
```

output.txt should look like this ===>

```
This is Datafile
Which contains Raw Data Make Sure To Clean this file 
Thanks in advance
```

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting of your input and output. Please check if this is what you want. Why do you expect `Thanks in advance` to appear as a separate line in the output when it follows a line that ends with a ``\`` in the input?

Comment: Yes Bodo .. This is exactly what I want.